# Post method never returns in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the below code snippet:

```
public async Task<LoginUser[]> GetUserAsync()
{
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = 
        new Uri("http://developer-platform.com/dutyfreebuzz/web_services/Login");
    StringContent str = new StringContent("username=admin&password=12345", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://developer-platform.com/dutyfreebuzz/web_services/Login/loginJSON"), str);
    var loginJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Rootobject rootobject = new Rootobject();
    if (loginJson != "")
    {
        //rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(loginJson);
    }
    //return rootobject.loginusers;
}
```

I have set the breakpoint to this function. During execution, the debugger is not moving to
`PostAsync` call and it is moving out of the function.

Comment: There is a currently known issue with setting breakpoints in async/await code in portable class libraries if the linker is enabled on iOS: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.1/ So you might be hitting this. There is a workaround where you disable linking for your iOS project. Are you maybe hitting that?

Comment: @Cheesebaron: Yes, I have linked to IOS. So how should I check for the response. I am developing using xamarin studio on my mac machine.

Comment: You could print out to the console. Also I don't think you need to set BaseAddress if you are using the full URL in PostAsync. However, I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: @ Cheesebaron: I solved the issue by setting a breakpoint on the response line code. But is takes a few minute for debugger to catch. Yes, I don't need the BaseAddress by mistake I forgot to comment.

Comment: @Cheesebaron - I have summarized the answer you have provided in the comments, if there is anythin furhter to add please Edit or update.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is a summary of comments by [Cheesebaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368379/cheesebaron) and OP, as the solution was provided in the comments.*

There is a currently known issue with setting breakpoints in `async`/`await` code in portable class libraries if the linker is enabled on iOS.

> [41836](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41836): For iOS apps, breakpoints within async methods in PCL projects
>   are not hit if the linker is enabled. Partial temporary workaround:
>   Set Project Properties > iOS Build > Linker behavior to Don't link.
>   (For device builds this workaround does unfortunately create
>   significantly larger .app bundles and can lengthen deployment times.)

As a work around set the break point in the `WriteLine()`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
```